# d3 interpolation mode not changing

Tags: d3.js

I was investigating an issue we found, and I narrowed it down to the interpolation mode which was causing our spline chart to dip below zero. I created a pen to illustrate the issue to a coworker. The problem that I'm having is that the `<select>` does not change the interpolation mode of the graph. Also, unless I add `.attr('d', line)` to the `path`, the chart doesn't render at all. I feel this should work as I used http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4342190 as a reference for how to change the interpolation mode dynamically.

Here's the pen http://codepen.io/gtb104/pen/meqNmZ?editors=001

Below is the JS from the pen.

```
const data = [
    { date: 1413733239000, close: 0 },
    { date: 1413743239000, close: 0 },
    { date: 1413753239000, close: 0 },
    { date: 1413763239000, close: 23 },
    { date: 1413773239000, close: 0 },
    { date: 1413783239000, close: 0 },
    { date: 1413793239000, close: 0 },
    { date: 1413803239000, close: 0 },
    { date: 1413813239000, close: 2 },
    { date: 1413823239000, close: 0 },
    { date: 1413833239000, close: 0 }
  ];
const margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  };
const width = 650 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date));

let y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.close));

let xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient('bottom');

let yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient('left');

let line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(d => x(d.date))
  .y(d => y(d.close))
  .interpolate('cardinal');

let svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append('path')
  .datum(data)
  .attr('class', 'line')
  .attr('d', line)//<-- I don't think this should be required here
  .call(redraw);

d3.select('#interpolate')
  .on('change', change)
  .selectAll('option')
  .data([
    'cardinal',
    'monotone'
  ])
  .enter().append('option')
  .attr('value', d => d)
  .text(d => d);

function redraw() {
  svg.select('path').attr('d', line);
};

function change() {
  line.interpolate(this.value);
  redraw();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change this line of code in your redraw function:

```
svg.select('path').attr('d', line);
```

to this:

```
svg.select('.line').attr('d', line);
```

Then it works. I think it has to do with the fact that your svg contains multiple paths (the x and y axis) and the example only has one. Targeting the class picks up the line you want to interpolate and works as expected.

Comment: Happens to us all! :)